# Default value for form entity

Tags: 8, entities

I'm using snippet code:

```
$user = User::create([
      'mail' => 'usemail@example.com',
      'name' => 'user_name',
    ]);
// $user->save();   I don't want create user here.
$form = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getFormObject('user', 'default')
  ->setEntity($user);
return \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm($form);
```

or

```
$user = User::create([
  'mail' => 'aaaa@gmail.com',
  'name' => 'user_name',
]);

return $this->entityFormBuilder()->getForm($user);
```

on my controller to render user form to custom page. I want to this form have some default value. Example mail and username. I don't want to use hook form alter.

Other way to set default value for entity form?

**Update:** a way I tried:

- Extend class [RegisterForm](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21RegisterForm.php/8.2.x)
- Override method form
- Tried two method $form_state->setStorage() and $form_state->setUserInput() like on [NodeForm](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21src%21NodeForm.php/class/NodeForm/8.2.x)

But doesn't working.

Comment: Your last example seems to be pretty much straightforward, why you are asking?

Comment: @4k4 I try it. But form still don't have default value. Or you say about hook_form_alter?

Comment: Tried it too, and indeed, it doesn't work. It does work for Node::create([...]) though. What is special about the user entity here?

Comment: I want to change follow register user. Wait user register verify by email before create user.

Comment: The difference between user and node is that node uses widgets, while the user form still uses custom code for those elements. User also has a custom register form mode with special logic for new users. In short, there is no way to do this without using form alter