# Route callback for RegisterForm results in Call to a member function getEntityTypeId() on null

Tags: 8, forms

**My objective**: Let say there is a role named "author". I would like to have a registration form having this path: `/register/author`, when the user submit, he/she will get the author role (same for any other roles like `/register/another_role`)

Here is what I have done:

1-Creating a route: last argument will be the role name

```
mymodule.register:
  path: '/register/{role}'
  defaults:
    _form: 'Drupal\mymodule\Form\RegisterByRole'
    _title: 'Register by role'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

2-Extending the RegisterForm Class

```
class RegisterByRole extends RegisterForm
{
    public function form(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $role = null)
    {
        $form = parent::form($form, $form_state);
        if (role_is_allowed($role)) {
            $form['test'] = [
                '#markup' => '<p>Test:' . $role
            ];
        }
        return $form;
    }
}
```

Of course I must change the submit function to assign the role, but I already have the following error when visiting the /register/author path:

```
Error: Call to a member function getEntityTypeId() on null in Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityForm->getBaseFormId() (line 111 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityForm.php).
```

I found that if I add the `__construct` and the `create` functions in the `RegisterByRole` class definition, the `getBaseFormId` error disappears... But I don't understand why?... And more annoying, I couldn't get the value of my $role argument (last arg of the route).

What is wrong in my plan?

Comment: Instead of a form route you could use a controller with a route parameter for the role, create a new user, add the role to the newly created user and then build the entity form with it by hand, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/230527/how-do-i-load-a-form-with-a-specific-form-display-form-mode

Comment: Many thanks for your comment, I could solve this issue by adding an _entity_form like explained by Jaypan. I think you idea is also nice... As requested by Jaypan, I will create a new Q&A for the remaining problem which is the role parameter not transmitted to the form.

Comment: You've asked for a plan. For entity forms the best place to transport initial values is the entity itself.

Comment: Thank you... I have to say that I don't undersand very well what you are saying: "transport initial values by the entity"... I have created a new Q&A for this topic as asked by Jaypan: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/291874/how-to-pass-a-parameter-to-a-route-of-type-entity-form

Comment: My plan is instead of transmitting the value to the form add it to the entity `$user->addRole($role);` and pass the entity to the form as shown in the linked question.

Comment: It took me some times to understand your brilliant idea... I don't know how to credit you!!! Here is what I have done: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/291874/how-to-pass-a-parameter-to-a-route-of-type-entity-form/291884#291884 Everything works well except that the role's checkbox is not checked in the register form (see my answer, not my question)

Comment: It seems that it is not possible to get the default value (role) of the User entity in the form (see: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/256966/default-value-for-form-entity) I have updated my answer to relfect this... Let me know how to credit your help.

Comment: @4k4 as I need to use the 'alter_form' method [ex: can't #disabled the roles's checkboxes inside the controller], then, why should I create a controller? Why not simply alias the 'user.register' route and alter my UI based on the aliased path (see [https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/structure-of-routes#s-alias-another-route] => hint I tested this solution but got a 'no access to this page'

Comment: My comments are about how to get the parameter inside of the form, once you have the parameter there you can operate on it in a subclass or a form alter hook, this depends on  whether you prefer OOP or old style hooks. - About using a controller: An entity form route is complicated because of a lot of helper functions in the background, So splitting the task into a simple controller which builds the form manually can make it much easier.

Comment: Finally, I end up with the OOP and I used your idea. As you said it is much simpler to use a controller which build the form. I have done what you said in your first comment. There is still a problem (or a bug): I create the new user, then I add the role and I pass this user to the form with `->setEntity($mynewuser)`. But unfortunately, the check box of the role is not checked in the displayed form... and if I save it like this, the user don't get the role... anyway I have made my own submit to handle this, but I feel this is a bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the problem is here:

```
_form: 'Drupal\mymodule\Form\RegisterByRole'
```

You need to use `_entity_form` rather than `_entity`, as the `RegisterForm` is actually an entity form for the User entity, as described in the Entity declaration for `\Drupal\user\Entity\User`:

```
"form" = {
  ...
  "register" = "Drupal\user\RegisterForm"
},
```

But to do this, you'll have to register a new form op for that class. You can do this in hook_entity_type_alter():

```
function hook_entity_type_alter(array &$entity_types) {
  $user = &$entity_types['user'];
  $user->setFormClass('role_registration', 'Drupal\example\Form\RegisterByRole');
}
```

Then, back in your route, you'll remove `_form` and instead implement`_entity_form`, setting it to to user.role_registration:

```
_entity_form: 'user.role_registration'
```

Comment: I feel like it's a good lead, but I don't know what to do: Should I replace "_form" by "_entity_form"? I am not sure, because, when doing this, I got this error: "RegisterByRole" entity type does not exist.

Comment: Sorry, my post needs more info, but I have no time to updated it now. I'll do it when I can. But you need to set the _entity_form something like 'user.role_register', then you will need to implement hook_entity_type_alter() and implement setFormClass() on the user type, passing the op as 'role_register' and your class as the value. I'll give some code later.

Comment: I think I understand... The plan is to use my  RegisterByRole's class for all register process (with setFormClass() )... It was not my first idea, but I hope it will work...

Comment: Updated but not yet confirmed.

Comment: Many thanks! This working... except that the $role parameter is not populated/working. I have also a question : why using hook_entity_type_alter and not hook_entity_type_build? (I have tried: both are working)

Comment: Alter alters the definition. That’s what you want. The build only covers the build.

Comment: Thank you. Regarding the $role parameter: how to access it from within `function form(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $role = null)` ? Why is it null when visiting `/register/author` and not equal to `author` ?

Comment: That's really a question for a different Q&A, for while passing the $role variable to the entity form is your next goal, the problem that this Q&A covered was using `_form` vs. `_entity_form`, which I believe has now been answered. 'How to pass a parameter to an entity form' is a different topic, that I myself haven't ever looked into, so I couldn't answer it in this issue anyways.

Comment: I have validate your answer and I have created a new Q&A: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/291874/how-to-pass-a-parameter-to-a-route-of-type-entity-form