# how to pass a parameter to a route of type _entity_form

Tags: entities, forms

With [some help](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/291862/route-callback-for-registerform-results-in-call-to-a-member-function-getentityty/291863#291863) I could create a route to an extended register form: as this form is an "entity form", my route have this type and the definition of this new form has been made in hook_entity_type_alter

The last part of the path of the route is a role name; and the user submitting this form (registering itself) should get this role.

Here is the code:

1-Extending the register form

```
class RegisterByRole extends RegisterForm
{
    public function form(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $role = null)
    {
        $form = parent::form($form, $form_state);
        if ($role) {
            $form['test'] = [
                '#markup' => '<p>Test:' . $role
            ];
        }
        return $form;
    }
}
```

2-Adding a new entity form to the entity_type definition/annotation

```
function my_module_entity_type_alter(array &$entity_types) {
    $entity_types['user']->setFormClass('role_registration', 'Drupal\my_module\Form\RegisterByRole');
}
```

3-Creating the route

```
my_module.register:
  path: '/register/{role}'
  defaults:
    _entity_form: 'user.role_registration'
    _title: 'Register by role'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

Unfortunatly, the $role parameter is not transmitted...

Answer (score 1):

With the help of [4k4](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/47547/4k4) who have all the credit for this answer, I have created a controler which, in turn, build my register form (I no longer need to **extend** the register form).
Before building the form, the controller must create a user and assign the role (coming from the parameter).

Here is the code

1-Create the route with rid as the parameter and a _controler key:

```
my_module.register:
  path: '/register/{rid}'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\my_module\Controller\RegisterByRoleController::content'
    _title: 'Register by role'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

2-Create the controller with rid as the parameter (src/Controller/...):

```
    public function content($rid=null) {

      $user_with_role = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::create();
      $roles = Role::loadMultiple();
      if ($rid && isset($roles[$rid])){
          $user_with_role->addRole($rid);
      }else{
          throw new \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException();
      }

      $form = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
      ->getFormObject('user', 'register')
      ->setEntity($user_with_role);

      $form_build=\Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm($form);

      //here is the trick I used to check the role
      $form_build['account']['roles'][$rid]['#checked']=TRUE;
      return $form_build;            
  }
```

Everything works well: the form is displayed, the rid is transmitted to the controller but the is still a problem:

The "transmitted" role's checkbox **is not checked** in the register form!

Any Hint?

I answer myself: it seems there is no way to achieve this "automatically", I will have to check "myself" the check boxes... see the last comment here: [Default value for form entity](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/256966/default-value-for-form-entity)

This is why is have added this line in the code `$form_build['account']['roles'][$rid]['#checked']=TRUE;`